# Dealing with quoted string within a where IN clause Oracle 9i

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i

I have the following query which works apart from when one of the values I need to search for has a single quote in the string. Its the only one like this and its breaking the query and i cant find a way to escape it that works.

```
   SELECT r.CREATED_DATE, r.AD_ID, 
                (select value FROM PBANK.AD_FIELDS WHERE FIELD_ID ='Jobtitle' AND ad_id = r.AD_ID) as job_title,
                (select value FROM PBANK.AD_FIELDS WHERE FIELD_ID ='Department' AND ad_id = r.AD_ID) as Department,
                (select forename || ' ' || surname FROM PBANK.users WHERE USER_PK_ID = R.RAISER_ID) as Raiser,
                (select status_name FROM PBANK.ATRSTATUS WHERE STATUS_ID = A.STATUS_ID) as status,
                A.STATUS_ID
                FROM PBANK.ATRREQUEST r 
                JOIN PBANK.ATRSTEP a on a.step_id = r.step_id AND a.ad_id = r.ad_id
                 LEFT JOIN PBANK.AD_FIELDS d on r.AD_ID = d.ad_id 
                WHERE acc_id='201050' 
                AND r.CREATED_DATE >= TO_DATE('2021-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
                AND r.CREATED_DATE <= TO_DATE('2021-04-30','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AND A.STATUS_ID = 'Approved' AND d.field_id = 'Department' AND d.value IN ('Retail Management','1st Floor Retail', 'Ground Floor Retail','Bar 3'6');
```

As you can see Bar 3'6 is what is causing me the issue. Is there a way to esacape this 'Bar 3'6' in Oracle 9i?

Comment: The SQL Standard is to double up the single quotes to represent a single quote in a string:  `'Bar 3''6'`

Comment: use \ in last string of your query it's causing issue 

'Bar 3\'6'